# How can you suppress click events of # hrefs?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I would like to auto suppress click events when the link href is a hash (#). I don't want to have to stop the event with e.preventDefault() within each view.

How can you stop click events application wide for # hrefs?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. The backbone routing gets fired before the default behavior, obviously. What you would have to do is insert an event handler that gets fired between the backbone routing and the default behavior, and then `e.preventDefault()`.

I believe that the order of execution of event handlers depends on the order in which they are defined. So play around with that somewhat. You can use the following to inspect the array of event handlers: `$(window).data('events');` (I'm assuming you're using jQuery?)

Comment: Yup - using Jquery. Searching around I found this solution [Backbone-Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js) - So on initialization of the app, they suppress the event before using the navigate method...Thoughts on this?

Comment: It looks like you could put your `preventDefault` right at the end of that script. Worth a try at least.

Comment: yea might just go ahead and do this. Thanks.